# HttpURLConnection returned different result on Android 5.1 and 4.4 while passing the same params

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
public static String request(String httpUrl, String httpArg) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String result = "";
    StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
    httpUrl = httpUrl + "?" + httpArg;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(httpUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("apikey", myAPpiKey);
        conn.connect();
        if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            String strRead = null;
            while ((strRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sbf.append(strRead);
                sbf.append("\r\n");
            }
            reader.close();
            result = sbf.toString();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Above code worked well on Android 5.1 and Android 6.0, and it returned correct result that I want. But when I ran these on Android 4.4, using the same params, it returned different result. I have tried several times, and attached debugger to the process. I found that the connection could be built successfully, and the **ResponseCode** was also **200**. 
I guess there must be something wrong with the HttpURLConnection params, so that the server returned different result. Did I set the params in a way that could work on Android 5.1 and 6.0 but not on 4.4? Can anybody tell me where did I do wrong?

Comment: What difference are you seeing?

Comment: @EJP It returns the information thatI want while on 5.1 or 6.0. But on 4.4,it returns "No information found" message.

Comment: @ZionQ : Please try my library https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking Thanks bro. Please try this and have some feedback.

Comment: When I encoded the httpArg to "UTF-8", problems was solved. I wonder why I don't need to do that on 5.1, does Android do it for me?

Comment: `No information found`. You are calling that `a differenr result` ? Very informative!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
URL url = new URL(httpUrl);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("apikey", myAPpiKey);
if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    .........
}
```

It works for me. Hope it will work.

Comment: Try it why? Setting chunked streaming mode only affects what is output to the request body, and there is no request body when the request method is GET.